# Dog hasn't eaten for four days, is pregnant. What to do?

Tags: dogs, diet, pregnancy

I discovered my dog is pregnant after I took her to the vet yesterday for not eating for three days. Today it has been four days of no eating. I got her to take a tiny bite of wet food last night, and a tiny bite today, but nothing substantial.

Is this normal for a pregnant dog? What would you do?

Comment: What did the vet tell you?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Not much actually. They told me to try either an appetite drug, or an anti-nausea drug. The anti-nausea drug didn't help. What helped is that I'm feeding my dog bits of human food which entice my dog to actually eat a little (because of the amazing new taste I suppose), but my dog still won't eat her regular food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's been a while. I hope your dog is well.
In case she isn't, in general I would take my dog to a vet immediately after 1 day of not eating.

If your vet's suggestions don't work you probably need to see another vet. 
Does she drink?

One thing I try is I cook some rice (no salt, no oil, just rice in water) and some chicken (no salt, no oil, absolutely no onions), mix them together and give it to my dog. It's easy to digest and dogs love it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up making something simple with beans, rice, and chicken. I wonder why she likes that enough to eat it while feeling bad, but not her dog food (that Purina Beyond food actually smells quite good!). Maybe possible she associated the food with sickness? I gradually got her back onto her dog food, little by little.